# Ajax and servlet Integration

Tags: ajax, servlets

I want to send the text using $.get() (ajax) function to a servlet for converting into image, and save it into sql database. After storing image into database i want to get the image as response in my page.

Answer (score -1):

what you want to send by ajax, image or data?

Comment: I want to send text data by ajax to servlet and convert it into image.